# Angular. Регулярное выражение, удаление текста между ><

Tags: typescript, angular

Получаю из Wysiwyg компонента текст с html тегами, такими как p и h в следующем виде:

```
<p></p>
<p>aaaaa</p><p>adfasdf</p>
<p>aaaaa</p><p>adfasdf</p><p></p><p></p>
```

Как мне получить только текст? В регулярках не силён)

Comment: А зря, время подучится. Если есть желание развиваться в IT. А тупо replaceAll() пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Помог просто replace: `.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '').trim();`